# In AngularJS -$http.get error : $http.get() is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I want to show the details of the image in which template Id is matched. For this, I use this code and get the error.

```
controller('TemplateDetailsCtrl',
         ['$scope', '$routeParams','$filter','$http',
  function($scope, $routeParams, $http, $filter) {
    var templateId = $routeParams.templateId;
    $http.get('json/templates.json').then(function(response){
      data = response.data
      $scope.template = $filter('filter')(data, function(d){
        return d.id == templateId;
      })[0];
    });
    $scope.mainImage = $scope.template.images[0].name;
}]);
```

Error:

> TypeError:
>
> ```
> $http.get is not a function
> at new <anonymous> (templates.js:25)
> at Object.instantiate (angular.js:5137)
> at $controller (angular.js:11688)
> at Object.link (angular-route.js:1251)
> at angular.js:1365
> at invokeLinkFn (angular.js:11235)
> at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:10554)
> at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:9801)
> at publicLinkFn (angular.js:9666)
> at lazyCompilation (angular.js:10080) "<div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">"
> ```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, your dependency injection is wrong.

Order of injections here:
`['$scope', '$routeParams','$filter','$http'`

have to match order in here:
`function($scope, $routeParams, $http, $filter)`

What more, I recommend you to take a look at the code guidelines for AngularJs, which are very well described here:
https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1

Your controller would look like:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').controller("TemplateDetailsCtrl", TemplateDetailsCtrl);

    TemplateDetailsCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams','$filter','$http'];

    function TemplateDetailsCtrl($scope, $routeParams, $filter, $http) {
        var vm = this;
        // your code
    }
})();
```

Such approach really makes the code much more readable and easier to maintain

Answer (score 0):

```
$http({url: "json/templates.json",
       method: "GET",
       params: undefined
       }).then(function(response){
           data = response.data
           $scope.template = $filter('filter')(data, function(d){
             return d.id == templateId;
       });
```

Comment: The `.success` method has been [removed from the AngularJS framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angularjs-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339).

Answer (score 0):

The dependency annotation is in the wrong order:

```
controller('TemplateDetailsCtrl',
         ̶[̶'̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶'̶,̶ ̶'̶$̶r̶o̶u̶t̶e̶P̶a̶r̶a̶m̶s̶'̶,̶'̶$̶f̶i̶l̶t̶e̶r̶'̶,̶'̶$̶h̶t̶t̶p̶'̶,̶
         ['$scope', '$routeParams','$http', '$filter',
  function($scope, $routeParams, $http, $filter) {
    var templateId = $routeParams.templateId;
    //....
}])
```

The `$filter` service was being injected in the place of the argument used for the `$http` service.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Dependency Injection - Inline Array Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#inline-array-annotation)